# Share input field value accross components in Angular

Tags: angular

I am experimenting with Angular 8. I have two forms in two different components that share some input values and they update every time the user leaves the input field.

Component 1 has these input fields

```
<input matInput [(ngModel)]="first" (blur)="newMessage()">
<input matInput [(ngModel)]="last" (blur)="newMessage()" >
```

and component 2 has these input fields

```
<input matInput [(ngModel)]="first2" >
<input matInput [(ngModel)]="last2" >
```

To share the values, I created a service that looks like this

```
export class DataService 
{

  private MessageSource = new BehaviorSubject<UserData[]>([]);

  currentMessage = this.MessageSource.asObservable();

  constructor( ) { }

  changeMessage(message : UserData[]){
        this.MessageSource.next(message)
  }

}
```

and the UserData class used

```
class UserData{
firstname : string
lastname : string
}
```

First component has this code associated with it

```
export class Comp1Component implements OnInit {

  message : UserData[]
  first : string
  last : string

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.first = message)
  }
name
  newMessage(){ 
    this.data.changeMessage(this.first)
  }
}
```

and the second looks like this

```
export class Comp2Component implements OnInit {

  message : UserData[]
  first2 : string
  last2: string

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.first2 = message)
  }
}
```

Right now this code updates the first input field on the second component. I would like to pass the second input value also, but I don't know what I have to do... Any ideas?

Here is the example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e5k2vm

If anyone could help, I would apprecciate it...

Comment: Use ReactiveForms instead. `FormControl`, `FormGroup` and `FormArray` are objects and can be easily passed anywhere whilst keeping the reference to the correct point

Comment: Your stackblitz shows a lot of errors on the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kxrugh)**

data.service

```
  private MessageSource = new BehaviorSubject<UserData>({});

  currentMessage = this.MessageSource.asObservable();

  constructor( )    { }

  changeMessage(message : UserData){
        this.MessageSource.next(message)
  }
```

.comp1

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => {
      this.first = message.first;
      this.last = message.last;
    });
  }
  name;
  newMessage() {
    this.data.changeMessage({ first: this.first, last: this.last });
  }
```

.comp2

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => {
      this.first2 = message.first;
      this.last2 = message.last;
    });
  }

  newMessage() {
    this.data.changeMessage({first:this.first2,last:this.last2});
  }
```

Comment: Apparently this code works on stackblitz but on vscode throws errors and fails to compile...  `````private MessageSource = new BehaviorSubject<UserData>({});`````  and this the error "Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UserData'.
  Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'UserData': firstname, lastname" Any clues?

Comment: You can add here `new UserData` or `new BehaviorSubject<any>({});`